# KDE Neon 5.x : wifi not installed after fresh OS installation

Tags: wifi, drivers, kde

After installed KDE neon 5.20 , I'm not able to detect my wireless networks.
After some research, I found that's because the **driver** is not installed automatically during installation of KDE neon.

Spec :

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure that your pc or laptop is connected to a LAN cable network.
Execute these commands in a terminal console :

```
 - sudo pkcon  update && apt-get upgrade 
 - sudo pkcon install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
 - sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Finally activate the wifi chipset with command : `sudo reboot`

It works for me.